# Ktor: Can't call App Engine Standard APIs

Tags: google-app-engine, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, ktor

I'm trying to run a simple Ktor server on Google App Engine Standard. If I run [their sample code on github](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-samples/tree/master/deployment/google-appengine-standard) it works well, but fails as soon as I call any App Engine API with the following message:

> Can't make API call memcache.Set in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager

All App Engine APIs trigger similar error messages. Is this related to how Ktor handles requests, and is there a way to make them work?

I think that the [Google Cloud java library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java) doesn't have this threading limitation, but unfortunately I can't use it. I need to access the App Engine Memcache service, which is only available through the App Engine APIs.